# Permanently Reordering Subtypes in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: file-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, arcgis-pro, domains, subtype

I have a feature class in a file geodatabase with **subtypes** (designed so when you select a country, you are presented with every province in that country as a series of domains).

I recently updated the name of a country from Saudia Arabia to Kingdom of Saudia Arabia. Everything is functioning normally, however, my subtypes are now out of order.

[image: Subtypes Out of Order]

I was unable to find a subtype manager in ArcCatalog or ArcMap. I used the one in ArcGIS Pro 2.0 and reordered the subtypes, and clicked Save. It appears that this adjustment was only temporary.

[image]

Is there a tool that sorts subtypes, somewhere?

Ideally, something like the [Sort Coded Value Domain](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/sort-coded-value-domain.htm) tool.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are misusing the subtype feature. It has been designed to be able to set various attributes on features to streamline creating new features. You are not creating any new country, so you would be better off with a geodatabase domain.

Unless you have a workflow where you **have to** use the subtypes and you need to keep them sorted, you would need to use a Python script to re-create all of them from scratch sorting in beforehand.

Look at this answer for details: [Can subtypes be re-ordered or a new subtype inserted in a specific position?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/223982/14435)

Comment: So the reason subtypes are used here is because we have a domain that is dependent upon another domain. I.e. In the first field, someone selects "United States", then the second field is limited to only US states to select.